# How to use TO_CHAR function functionality in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `EMP`. I know how to use `TO_CHAR` function in TOAD but how to get same output if I use in SQL Server 2008. Is there any conversion function in SQL Server for `TO_CHAR`?

Please help me in writing a query in SQL Server.

Thanks in advance...

```
 select * 
 from emp 
 where to_char(hiredate, 'yy') like '82';
```

Output

```
     EMPNO  ENAME    JOB      MGR    HIREDATE       SAL   COMM   DEPTNO
     7934   MILLER   CLERK    7782   23-JAN-82     1300           10
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `HIREDATE` is either a `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype, then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE YEAR(HIREDATE) = 1982 -- I think that this is the year you want
```

Now, that code won't be able to use an index on `HIREDATE` if there exists one, so you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE HIREDATE >= '19820101' 
AND HIREDATE < '19830101'
```

On the other hand, if you actually want to use the `LIKE '82'` condition, meaning that you want results for 1882, 1982, 2082, .... then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE DATENAME(YEAR,HIREDATE) LIKE '%82'
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008 all explicit conversions are done with `CAST` and `CONVERT`.  See [here for the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

For your explicit case, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(4), hiredate, 121),2) like '82';
```

(well, actually, I would probably use the `YEAR` function and keep it numeric instead, but if I really needed it to be as a string, then like this)

Answer (score 1):

Many different ways.  Here are two from me.

```
-- If a string, just select right two
declare @temp1 varchar(9) = '23-JAN-82'
select right(@temp1, 2) as yy;


-- If a date, just use japan format
declare @temp2 datetime = '23-JAN-82'
select convert(char(2), @temp2, 11) as yy
```