# How to use TO_Char() in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert the SQL statement to SQL Server 2008. So how can I do this? Below is my sql statement which I want to convert. I also try to resolve from the Stackoverflow question but I am not succeeding [How to use TO_CHAR function functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462406/how-to-use-to-char-function-functionality-in-sql-server-2008)

```
SELECT 
    C_Debt_Payment.AD_Client_ID,  
   (CASE WHEN C_Debt_Payment.AD_Client_ID IS NULL THEN '' 
         ELSE (COALESCE(TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(COALESCE(TO_CHAR(table1.Name), ''))),'') ) END) AS AD_Client_IDR
```

Thanks for your reply and comments

Comment: In sql server you can use CONVERT or CAST.

Comment: @SeanLange i was try but not success can you please tell me what i shall write this for convert

Comment: `TO_CHAR(table1.Name)` seems rather unnecessary to begin with. `name` usually indicates a that has the type `varchar` (or any other character type) - using to_char() on that seems questionable. What datatype is the column `name`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name varchar

Comment: Then `to_char(name)` is totally useless and can be removed from the original query alltogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_CHAR` is Oracle. In SQL Server, use `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT C_Debt_Payment.AD_Client_ID,  
  (CASE WHEN C_Debt_Payment.AD_Client_ID IS NULL THEN '' ELSE COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(20),table1.name),'') END) AS AD_Client_IDR
```